# Use `\(...\)` in `algpseudocode`

Tags: algorithmicx, inline, algpseudocode, robust-commands

Is there a way to use the newer `\(...\)` math syntax in arguments for any commands from `algpseudocode` (`algorithmicx`)? The documentation and virtually any other tutorial uses the TeX-primitive `$...$`.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \For{\(i \gets 0\) to \(n\)}   % breaks
            \State \Call{Foo}{\(i\)}   % breaks
        \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With "algpseudocodex", the environment "algorithm" does not exist, and i don't understand the problem to use $...$

Comment: @pascal974 Oh yeah, I forgot `\usepackage{algorithm}". The reason why `\(...\)` should be used is that 1st it is the newer (and recommended) syntax and 2nd my whole project / all of my snippets use it.

Comment: I don't recommend the `\(`, `\)` syntax. So, this syntax is not generally recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get no error from `\For{\(i \gets 0\) to \(n\)}`. But the error comes from `\Call{Foo}{\(i\)}` because `\Call` eventually becomes

```
#1#2->\textproc {#1}\ifthenelse {\equal {#2}{}}{}{(#2)}
```

and `\equal{#2}` fails when it is passed something that contains LaTeX robust commands, because it attempts doing full expansion.

You can fix this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\algrenewcommand\Call[2]{%
  \textproc{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{#2}}{}}{}{(#2)}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \For{\(i \gets 0\) to \(n\)}
            \State \Call{Foo}{\(i\)}
        \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, more efficiently,

```
\algrenewcommand\Call[2]{%
  \textproc{#1}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else(#2)\fi
}
```

There are other two places that might need such fix, so a complete version should be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

%%% fix for usage of \ifthenelse
\newcommand{\algparenthesize}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else(#1)\fi
}
\algdef{SE}[PROCEDURE]{Procedure}{EndProcedure}[2]
 {\algorithmicprocedure\ \textproc{#1}\algparenthesize{#2}}
 {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicprocedure}
\algdef{SE}[FUNCTION]{Function}{EndFunction}[2]
 {\algorithmicfunction\ \textproc{#1}\algparenthesize{#2}}
 {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfunction}
\algrenewcommand\Call[2]{\textproc{#1}\algparenthesize{#2}}
%%% end fix

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \For{\(i \gets 0\) to \(n\)}
            \State \Call{Foo}{\(i\)}
        \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing, you just made `algorithmicx` robust. How about asking the maintainer to fix this? I assume this fix still works with the old `$...$`.

Comment: @Gargantuar Yes, of course it works. I'm not sure whether `algpseudocode` is being maintained: the last release was in 2005.